# Switcing HTTP client to CCS (XMPP) Client

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have a simple chat application installed on Android devices and can send notification via GCM HTTP.
I want to switch backend implementation from GCM HTTP to CCS XMPP.
Can I use same pntoken get from mobile devices registered previously to send push notification?
Is it required additional implementation at mobile device side?

I mean when I change the change the GCM connection interface from GCM HTTP to CSS XMPP Do I need to additional data from mobile devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No changes on device side are required. You can use same registration ids as before.